# return many render in the same function in views.py in django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem in django.
In fact, i would return many render(request,template.html,{'x':val}) in the same function in views.py; i mean the variable x in the template.html will be changed
with many different values val and each value is at a given moment.

Code views.py:

```
def test(request):
    test1 = "true"
    test2 = "true"

    if test1 == "true":
        val= 50
        return render(request,'template.html', {'x':val})
    if test2 == "true":
        val= 20
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'x':val})
```

I would in the first, it return the value 50 in the tempalte.html after its recharge page and return the value 20.

Any one can help me?

Comment: the code in views.py :
`def test(request):
  test1 = "true"
  test2 = "true"
  if test1 == "true":
     val= 50
     return render(request,'template.html', {'x':val})
  if test2 == "true":
     val= 20
     return render(request, 'template.html', {'x':val})
`

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36998584/edit) button to add information, although your question is unclear

Comment: i have add the code of views.py ;                                                                        in fact , i would to use a progress bar what is created with css in a template.html and i would to add the value of this progress bar from function in views.py. This function have many tasks to do and they are long running tasks so i would after a task is terminate , the value of the progress bar have change and increase

Comment: you can send all the values at once to the template and inside the template you can use timer function or other javascript function to change the page values

Comment: but i can't use a timer function because the time of the execution of the function change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think... you want to send or receive signals between server and client asynchronously.

If this is right you want, I think there are three solutions.

- ajax
- [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio)
- [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)

I hope it will help

Comment: thanks for your response , this is exactly that i would to do but i don't konw how to do this with ajax? it is the same function in views.py so it return templates once

Comment: If you use ajax, i think that you have to send repeatedly a signals to server. Server returns a progress of tasks.

Comment: yes , i use ajax but how to send signals to server from a template?

Comment: $.ajax('progress_url', {success: function(d) { //update progress }})  requests repeatedly to server

Comment: and the progress_url is the url of the function in views.py?

Comment: You have two choices. You can create a new view and url or edit your `test` view. If you create a new view and url, you would insert new url. If you edit your `test` view, you could use `is_ajax()` function and insert url of `test` view. You can reference to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax